# Run similar tests with Mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

### Background

I am scrapping a wikia for information, and before I actually do that, I wanna make sure I can connect to the wikia servers.

Best way to do it? Using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) tests with my nodejs app!

### Objective

I have a configuration file, which has an object with all the links I want. I have a battery set called "connection" and I want each test to try to connect to the wikia.

```
{
    "sources": {
        "wikia": {
            "link": "http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki",
            "pages": {
                "mods_2.0": "/Mods_2.0",
                "warframe_mods": "/Category:Warframe_Mods",
                //more links follow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The problem here is that I don't want to write and replicate the same test for over a dozen wikia pages. I want to avoid repetition.

My solution to this, was to put every `it` inside a loop, however, the code breaks because my `wikiaPages` arrays is always undefined, even when I use the `before()` function.

### Code

```
let assert = require("assert");
let superagent = require("superagent");
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");

const SCRAPER_CONFIG_FILE = "./scraperConfig.json";

describe("connection", () => {

    let wikiaUri;
    let wikiaPages;
    let completeUri;

    before(() => {
        let config = jsonfile.readFileSync(SCRAPER_CONFIG_FILE);
        wikiaUri = config.sources.wikia.link;
        wikiaPages = Object.values(config.sources.wikia.pages);
    });

    for(let pageUri of wikiaPages) {

        completeUri = wikiaUri + pageUri;

        it("connects to " + completeUri, done => {
            superagent.get(completeUri, (error, res) => {
                assert.ifError(error);
                assert.equal(res.status, 200);
                done();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

### Questions

- How can I fix this code, so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move it out of your before block:

```
describe("connection", () => {
    const config = jsonfile.readFileSync(SCRAPER_CONFIG_FILE);
    const wikiaUri = config.sources.wikia.link;
    const wikiaPages = Object.values(config.sources.wikia.pages);

    before(() => {
    });

    for(let pageUri of wikiaPages) {

        completeUri = wikiaUri + pageUri;

        it("connects to " + completeUri, done => {
            superagent.get(completeUri, (error, res) => {
                assert.ifError(error);
                assert.equal(res.status, 200);
                done();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the point of having a `before` function then, if I can always just put everything outside it?

Comment: before can be async for example which the outside can't . Another thing is, that you can bind variables to the this object inside before which is accessable in your it -blocks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your loop `wikiaPages` happens on declaration stage, which is before `before` stage, so `wikiaPages` is not yet assigned a value.

Unwrapping `before` hook so reading config file and setting `it`s happens on declaration stage should make it work:

```
let assert = require("assert");
let superagent = require("superagent");
let jsonfile = require("jsonfile");

const SCRAPER_CONFIG_FILE = "./scraperConfig.json";

describe("connection", () => {

    let wikiaUri;
    let wikiaPages;
    let completeUri;


    let config = jsonfile.readFileSync(SCRAPER_CONFIG_FILE);
    wikiaUri = config.sources.wikia.link;
    wikiaPages = Object.values(config.sources.wikia.pages);

    for(let pageUri of wikiaPages) {

        completeUri = wikiaUri + pageUri;

        it("connects to " + completeUri, done => {
            superagent.get(completeUri, (error, res) => {
                assert.ifError(error);
                assert.equal(res.status, 200);
                done();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the point of having a `before` function then, if I can always just put everything outside it?